# How do sites like Imgur avoid Copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

How do companies like Imgur avoid getting sued. Some of their users upload copyrighted material.

I want to build a site similar to Imgur, where the user can upload images and gifs.

I am worried about being sued for copyright infringement.
I am only going to provide a service for uploading images to a site, where everyone can view them.

Can I get sued for what the user uploads?

I am more than happy to remove any copyrighted material. 
If a user asks me to remove an image they claim is copyrighted, can I ask for proof?

If a user decides to upload porn can I get in trouble for it?
Example: A kid browses my site and sees something he is not suppose to see.

This is a hobby project and I will be the only person working on it.

I currently reside in Norway. I am not a Norwegian citizen. I am a Namibian citizen. Namibia doesn't have any extradition treaties with the USA. I am not sure which laws apply to me concerning copyright.

Comment: In the U.S., Imgur (and any other site that hosts arbitrary user contributions) is safe from its users' infringement under the "safe harbor" provisions of the DMCA, as long as the site operators (1) are not aware of specific infringing works on the site, (2) do not encourage users to commit copyright infringement, and (3) promptly respond to take-down requests under DMCA protocol. I do not know what laws apply to you if you opperate your site in Norway as a Nambian citizen, though. Also, the laws that limit liability for copyright infringment may differ from laws about pronographic content.